# Facebook let user Invite all friends to try app

Tags: ios, facebook, share, invite

A few apps that are not games are offering their users the ability to invite all their facebook friends to try an iOS app.

**Workflow**

1. user presses invite friends
2. popup prompt to invite all friends
3. user accepts
4. facebook prompt user wants to access your friends
5. user accepts
6. all friends get invited

**Mainly**

- How are they getting access to all their users?
- What method are they using to send the requests?

**Considerations:**

- Are they using and old SDK, API or iOS Social framework?
- Was the app registered a long time ago?

Here is Meow Chat who I've confirmed is currently doing it.

**APP Prompt:**

[image: meow chat popup]

**End user notifications:**

[image: end user image]

I have found similar questions but not one that addresses this exactly or that provides an answer.

Comment: This feels fairly straightforward - when you link your FB in the app they're doing a permission check to have access to your friends list that almost everyone just says yes to. So when you tell them to invite your friends, then all they do is hit FB's API to get your current friends, then send them all an invite through Facebook's API. Almost no work is done on the mobile - all it does in this process is ask for your permission to access your friends list. It's in the request for FB's session so once they accept, it gets pushed up automatically to their account on FB.

Comment: You can read about how to invite people at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq

Comment: Have you found any solution? Friends request returns only people who already installed app, so is seems useless...

Comment: The original solution seemed to use an old sdk. That solution might not be around any more.. We ended up deciding this was bad practice and opted against it.

Comment: Thanks, also couldn't find any solution except old SDK.